# Custom error message for postgresql check constrint

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, constraints

I have the "valid_id" check constraint on my requests table. But when it violates the constraint it shows following error

> ERROR: new row for relation "requests" violates check constraint
>   "valid_name" DETAIL: Failing row contains ....

But instead of that I want to show message like **"Failed to insert record. name is required".**

Is there any way to show the custom error message in PostgreSQL?

Comment: have you tried to rename the constraint?

Comment: My bad. Its "valid_name" Whenever I try to insert the null in the name field then it gives the error but instead of that I want to show my custom error message

Comment: You could name it `Failed_to_insert_record_name_is_required` instead of `valid_name`.

Comment: check also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/how-to-customize-constraint-violation-messages

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of advanced territory here because you want to be pretty familiar with SQL states as well as existing error messages before you get started.  Note that you want to re-used existing sql states as appropriate so that the application doesn't know you have overridden your check constraint.

But what you can do is create a function which runs the check and issues a `raise exception` if the check fails.  Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_is_not_null(value text, column_name text) RETURNS BOOL 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
begin
   IF $1 IS NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error:  % is required', $2;
   END IF;
   RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$;
```

If you are using 8.4 or higher, you can specify an SQL state.

Comment: Note that you still can't control the *whole* error message produced by `psql` or most other PostgreSQL clients. For example, `psql` will always prefix `ERROR: ` or the appropriate translation for the currently active language.

Comment: @CraigRinger  More specifically, psql prefixes such messages with the error level and a colon, right?  `FATAL:`, `WARNING:`, and `NOTICE:`

Comment: Yes, at the default error verbosity level. The error level is IIRC a translatable string, but should be easy to strip by dropping everything before the colon. Other clients may behave differently, eg PgJDBC.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure where the prefix creeps in but in Java at least, if you cast the SQLException up to PSQLException (the postgres specialization) then you can get the raw message without any 'ERROR:' prefix using
psqle.getServerErrorMessage().getMessage();